# ShowWindow spawns unexpected windows/application

Tags: c#, winapi, showwindow

I'm trying to pop notepad window in my c# Application using this code:

```
Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
Debug.WriteLine("Processes: " + Processes.Length);

// do something
foreach(Process p in Processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
    SetForegroundWindow(p.Handle);
    ShowWindow(p.Handle, ShowWindowEnum.Show);
    //SetActiveWindow(p.Handle);

    //p.Kill();
}
```

The console logs "notepad" just fine. I can even kill notepad process. However, for some reason, showWindow works randomly. Most of the time it spawns something like GDI+server titled empty windows and etc and rarely pops the notepad.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This never works out well. Don't expect to host windows from other processes without their cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowWindow` expects a window handle, not a process handle.

Try passing the `MainWindowHandle` instead.

```
SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowEnum.Show);
```

This should be ok for Notepad.exe, but won't be generally reliable for applications that have multiple top level windows.